# Mongodb. How to clean orphans with race condition?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, race-condition

I have a task which I got a little stuck. We have 2 entities:
[image]

One book has only one author, one author can have multiple books.
I have to implement a function of "removing" author which doesn't have any books. It could happen if I removed old books, for example.
Also I have several restrictions:

1. Books and authors should be saved in separate collections.
2. Each entity shoud be present in mongo only once, we even use `unique indexes` for that.
3. I can't put author directly into book entity, I can create only id link, using plain id or DBRef.
4. Author has to have at least one book and each book has to have non-null link to author.

In other words I have to keep some kind of [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

The task is quite simple if you make sequential requests, but I have quite aggressive concurrent environment and I get `null` links quite ofthen:

1. Remove an old book with author "A" -> the author "A" doesn't have books anymore
2. **In parallel:** 
   2.1. Request for creating a new book "B" with author "A" -> creates the new book "B" with the link to author "A" 
   2.2. Request for removing orphan authors -> remove author "A". (since, the **2.1** haven't finished yet)
3. Since Mongo doesn't have any constraints, we get the new book "B" with the link to author "A" which is already removed.

I've tried transactions and optimistic locking, but it seems, they don't solve the problem at some corner cases. Other solutions don't fit in restrictions which I described above.
How can I solve the current task with the such restrictions in `Mongo`? Is that even possible?

Comment: Does the system need to be 100% accurate 100% of the time? or can you tolerate some inconsistencies? 
can books be updated or just created? do books have some incremental counter?

Comment: To be honest, I'm trying to keep the system consistent as much as possible, but I open for any possible solutions. Some inconsistencies we can accept, other not completely.

Comment: Books don't change at all, but again if solution requires it, I can accept it.

Comment: Books don't have any incremental counters yet. Just Id, link  to author and payload, but I can add any necessary field. Actually, I've already tried to add something like "version" field for optimistic locking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following solution, first we need to create a new field `bookCount` for authors, this reflects the # of books they have in the system.

```
// remove book flow:
// start transaction
db.collection.book.removeOne({ _id: bookId });
db.collection.author.updateOne( { _id: authorId } , {$inc: {bookCount: -1} );
// I personally prefer moving this to a TLL index to handle but can be done here.
db.collection.author.deleteOne({ _id: authorId, bookCount: 0 })
// end transaction
```

```
// new book flow:
// start transaction
db.collection.book.insertOne(newBook);
db.collection.author.updateOne( { _id: authorId } , {$inc: {bookCount: 1}, { upsert: true} );
// end transaction
```

Technically you don't need transactions here if you assume the `updateOne` always succeeds, this is true as long as there are no crashes for the app and db, if it simplifies things I would go with this approach and add a cleanup task to run after a crash.

Now the race condition is solved, because all mongodb operations are atomic author will never be deleted if it has more than 1 book, if the starts align and it was deleted just before the "new" book update the `upsert` will "recreate" the author in the db. Again without transactions very minor inconsistencies are possible but with transactions this is sound.

Comment: I'm implemented my solution using `findAndModify` with `upsert`. The task was solved thanks to your tips, and, to be honest the solution is pretty the same, as you suggest. Thank you!